# Bixby, Multiple HTTP calls in a single Javascript Function?

Tags: javascript, bixby

I know bixby developer studio is brand new, but I am having an issue making two http calls in one javascript function, first one to get a custom identifier from a service and then a second to get data from the service based on that identifier.

I have tried the following things:

```
module.exports.function = function(phoneNumber,couponBrand)
{
     if(phoneLookup(phoneNumber))
     {
        return getCoupons(couponBrand)
     }
     else
     {
       return null
     }
}
```

Which doesn't call either of the functions...
So then I tried calling the first function as a precondition like so:

```
module.exports = {
  function:getCoupons,
  preconditions:[phoneLookup]
}
```

Which doesn't call the function, but only calls the precondition function...
I also then tried doing a very nodeJS callback scheme where inside of the phoneLookup function I called the getCoupons function and passed a function as a parameter then at the end of the getCoupons function I invoke the parameter function as a callback while passing the values obtained in the phoneLookup function, like so:

```
function getCoupons(json,callback)
{
    var endpoint = //removed for security
    var body = //removed for brevity
    var options = //removed for brevity
    var response = http.postUrl(endpoint,body,options)
    var json = response.parsed
    callback(json)
}

module.exports.function = function phoneLookup(phoneNumber,couponBrand)
{
    var endpoint = //removed for security
    var body = //removed for brevity
    var options = //removed for brevity
    var response = http.postUrl(endpoint,body,options)
    var json = response.parsed

    getCoupons(json,function(results)
    {
        return results
    })
}
```

Sadly, this doesn't call the callback function or at least doesn't wait for the second http call in the getCoupons function to finish before returning to model I have listed in the output...

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Your functions don't return anything, they use callbacks to propagate the result. That's why this `if(phoneLookup(phoneNumber))` is not working and this `return getCoupons(couponBrand)` wouldn't work. Check out [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) wich is built on top of Promises.

Comment: What's your model for this action? What are the models for the `phoneNumber` and `couponBrand` concepts?

Comment: phoneNumber and couponBrand are simple concepts:

    `integer (PhoneNumber) 
    {
      description (The phone number associated to the customers account.)
    }`
    `text (CouponBrand) 
    {
      description (The brand of the coupon)
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Coding JavaScript functions in bixby is a little different, because everything runs synchronously. Avoid code that relies on promises or callbacks, because it may not work.

Here's a sample function from the docs, illustrating an HTTP GET. Try modifying it to use your code.

https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/http/blob/master/code/FindShoeFiltering.js

```
module.exports.function = function findShoe (type) {
  console.log("FindShoe filter by a specific type")
  var options = { 
    format: 'json',
    query: {
      type: type
    }
  };
  // If type is "Formal", then this makes a GET call to /shoes?type=Formal
  var response = http.getUrl(config.get('remote.url') + '/shoes', options);
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Right, I have seen that, but what happens if I need to do two requests inside one function?

Comment: Then you make those two requests and return whatever your action function should return. It's linear code: `var resp1 = http.getUrl(...); var resp2 = http.getUrl(...); ... return ...;`

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can just simply call 2 functions sequentially.

like below,

```
function getCoupons(json,callback)
{
    var endpoint = //removed for security
    var body = //removed for brevity
    var options = //removed for brevity
    var response = http.postUrl(endpoint,body,options)
    var json = response.parsed
    return json
}

module.exports.function = function phoneLookup(phoneNumber,couponBrand)
{
    var endpoint = //removed for security
    var body = //removed for brevity
    var options = //removed for brevity
    var response = http.postUrl(endpoint,body,options)
    var json = response.parsed

    return getCoupons(json)
}
```

And, if you call http.xxxxUrl, your function waits for response.
Bixby's javascript code runs sequentially. It does not support both async call and multi thread